# IO.UnsupportedOperation: Not Writable

Tags: python, file

I have made a program where it stores a score attached with a name in a *.txt* file. However, I want to then print the alphabetical order of the name attached to the score. But when I run the program it come up with the error `io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable`
Here my code:

```
            file = open(class_name , 'r')       #opens the file in 'append' mode so you don't delete all the information
            name = (name)
            file.write(str(name + " : " )) #writes the information to the file
            file.write(str(score))
            file.write('\n')
            lineList = file.readlines()
            for line in sorted(lineList):
                print(line.rstrip());
                file.close()
```

Comment: What language and platform is this?

Comment: The language is python.

Answer (score 5):

You have opened the file read only, then attempted to write to it.
With the file left open, you then attempt to read from it, where even if it was in append mode, the file pointer would be at the end of the file.
Try this instead:

```
class_name = "class.txt"
name = "joe"
score = 1.5
file = open(class_name , 'a')       #opens the file in 'append' mode so you don't delete all the information
name = (name)
file.write(str(name + " : " )) #writes the information to the file
file.write(str(score))
file.write('\n')
file.close()
file = open(class_name , 'r') 
lineList = file.readlines()
for line in sorted(lineList):
    print(line.rstrip());
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to close the file multiple times. Try this:

```
with open(class_name , 'w+') as file:
    name = (name)
    file.write(str(name + " : " )) #writes the information to the file
    file.write(str(score))
    file.write('\n')
    for line in sorted(lineList):
        print(line.rstrip());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the file in read mode `r` which only allows reading the file `r+` allows reading and writing of file. You can refer [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)